# Icons are not appearing in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` to show icons and `react-navigation` for showing tabs. I am trying to show Home icon in button navigation but icons are not appearing.

PFB relevant code of Icon and `createBottomTabNavigator`

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
// import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import Account from '../../Form/components/Account';
import Home from '../../Layout/components/Home';

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Account: { 
    screen: Account,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Account',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="rocket" size={35} color="#fdc94c" />
    }
  },
  Home: { 
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="rocket" size={35} color="#fdc94c" />
    },
 }
}, {
  order: ['Home', 'Account'],
  tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: true,
      showIcon: true,
      activeBackgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        height: 60
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
      }
    }
})
```

PFB screenshot as well.

What do I need to do to show icon of Home?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the font is linked in your iOS workspace, by using `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` then rebuild the app

Follow the documentation and make sure that everything is set as they mentioned
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios

Answer (score 1):

Run command npm i -g rnpm. And run the rnpm link on project folder. Then run the project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you pasted this in app level gradle `android\app\build.gradle`?

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Comment: if this doesnt work then copy alll the font files from node_modules/react-native-vector_icons/Fonts and paste it in android/app/src/main/assets/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your project folder.

$react-native link